# Is there a database for stars?

Tags: star, photography

I'm interested, is there any database of stars which I could browse on the internet?
It would be good, because I could read their parameters, features and maybe find a picture about it.
Thanks!

Comment: http://www.usno.navy.mil/USNO/astrometry/optical-IR-prod/nomad is the biggest one, but that page may help you find smaller ones.

Answer (score 2):

HD? Perhaps start with: [VizeR](http://vizier.u-strasbg.fr/viz-bin/VizieR). You can search for any star you like, regardless of catalogue.